# IE 8 and PDF can not load

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer-8, fiddler

I have a very strange issue on my website with IE 8 in particular.  Smaller size PDF is able to load in IE8, but any pdf that's a bit bigger (around 3mb),simply can not be loaded. It always say something like "170kb loaded out of 2.3mb", you refresh it again, the size increase to "340kb loaded out of 2.3mb", but nothing shows.

I read that I have to set the header Cache-Control of the website to "no-cache, no-store", changed it. Now the pdf loads, but only load the first page. Then freeze.

The strange thing is this. I tried to debug the header information in IE8 by loading fiddler. Whenever Fiddler is loaded, the problem disappear.

What's wrong?

ps: it's under https

Thanks

Comment: What PDF viewer are you using?  What other browsers have you tried?

Comment: Adobe Reader X and tried in firefox, chrome, all works. What's more strange is Fiddler. Everytime when it's loaded, the problem disappear.

Comment: Does the problem exists with IE9, IE10, IE11?

Comment: I don't have IE 9+, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: MS provides free virtual machines with those versions of IE installed